# Convert datetime to date of a column in where condition using sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Okay,

I want to convert column datetime to date while querying.

Can anyone help me out with sequelize query of below given query ?

```
select * from ev_events where DATE(event_date) <= '2016-10-10'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `sequelize.fn`:

```
Event.findAll({
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('date', sequelize.col('event_date')), '<=', '2016-10-10')
})
```

I've had to guess how you have defined your model.

Comment: Yeah this is the way to do it. This is how i did it 

sequelize.where(sequelize.cast(mods.sequelize.col('event_date'), 'DATE'), '>=', from_date).

But thanks for the help :)

Comment: How do you do with this type of query to add a AND something_id = 45 ?

Comment: @Sachacr You can do that by `{ 
  where: { 
        [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
           { id: 45 }, 
           Sequelize.where('date', '=', '2018-05-13')
        ]
   }
}`

Comment: @KeyurSakaria 's answer in comment worked for me(I only had to remove mods.). The accepted answer didn't work for me. I got error - 'date' is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
sequelize.and(
  {id: '111'},
  sequelize.where(
    sequelize.fn('date', sequelize.col('event_date')), 
    '<=', '2016-10-10'
  )
)
```